# loading multiple html textboxes in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html

I need to load multiple values from my database. I have used java to load these values then i pass them to a textbox in html so that i can load them in my javscript portion of the code.

Since there is no provision for array in html, I have appended `'i'` in the following code to achieve my purpose.

`input type=text name=lat<%=i%> value="<%=l1%>"`

So I get values like `lat1`, `lat2`, `lat3` and so on.

How do I call them from javascript without having to write for lat1,lat2 etc. seperately

`//var a=document.f1.lat1.value;`

Basically how can I replace '1' with 'i' in the above line

Comment: Java and javascript is pretty different, are u sure youre using java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript bracket notation is what you are after

```
document.f1["lat" + i].value
```